# How to set font-family: Arial; in Tailwind?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

How do I set font-family: Arial; in Tailwind?
I'm using React and Tailwind on my project.
I'm using other Google font as * (applies all) and I want to use Arial in certain parts.
It's not working.
Also do I delete the default font-family in body tag (index.css) ?
Any help is appreciated.

Desired Font
[image]

How I did to customize the font in Tailwind.
tailwind.config

```
extend: {
   fontFamily: {
      "font-Arial": ["Arial"],
   },
```

index.jsx

```
<p className="font-Arial">Lorem Lorem Lorem</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the string name like this:

```
fontFamily: {
   arial: ["Arial"],
}
```

And then you can call it using the className `"font-arial"`

Also, if still not working, you need to place your fontFamily outside of the "extend" property in talwind.config file, so it can load by default.

Comment: Checked! Did I do it right?